# Best way to save traffic in iOS Parse App

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, traffic

I have a logic problem in my app using Parse, Regarding which path to choose to save in traffic, and if someone has already faced a similar problem, I will really appreciate the help. Also, you can end up helping other developers facing the same problem

I have a social app where there is a feed with objects, and users can bookmark ("favorite") these objects

I studied the Parse documents and concluded that among the pointers, relations and arrays, the best way to store favorite would be a objectId's array stored in the class of users. Each time an object is bookmarked by the user, the ObjectID of this object is stored in a objectID's array belonging to that user. The reason for the choice is:

1. It is easy to create the bookmark's view and show them to the user, since I just have to search for the user's ObjectID's array and finding those present in the class of objects
2. Saving only the objectID and not the entire object, I will save in traffic and I keep the app and traffic clean

But my logic problem is as follows. If user1 has created an object, and user2 bookmarked it, and then user1 decided to delete the object, I would have to search the objectID of this deleted object in each favorite array of each user!

So my question is, what would be less expensive for traffic of my App? Store the entire object when a user bookmark it, automating removal when a user deletes the object? Or just store the ObjectID, and perform the search on each array for each user when this object is deleted?

Comment: I've never done this, but I have researched how to reduce the amount of traffic to and from the cloud. I believe implementing Cloud Code (via Parse) is your solution to keeping traffic to a minimal. If you didn't want to do that, I would just present a view that says user1 has deleted the object, per request of user2 to view their bookmarked object. hope that makes sense, or helps, in any way.

Comment: Store the object reference in the user and use an `afterDelete` cloud code function.

Comment: @justColbs, this is an excellent idea. I'm still not familiar with the use of the Cloud Code, so I did not think seriously about the idea but I think it would be strictly the best way to accomplish this

Comment: just like @Paulw11 said, this should be the best way to accomplish this

Comment: @Paulw11, just dropping by to say that I learned Cloud Code and everything worked like a charm!

Comment: I also using the code not as Cloud Code but as a background job where I run it once a day and verify if there is any object in the arrays users that is not present anymore in the object class, i.e, if there are any deleted objects in the users array of bookmarked

Comment: I thought that doing this way will reduce the amount of times I perform the code, as remove this piece of information (the objectID from the users bookmarked array) is not a urgent task and dont need to be performed immediately. What do you think @Paulw11? Should I run the code after every object is deleted, or should I just perform a search once a day or two for deleted objectsIDs in users arrays?

Comment: just one more thing, don't feel obligated to answer this and the previous comments if you don't have time since the answer already was informally answered by you. If you just post an formal answer on the threat saying: "Just use Cloud Code dude", I will happily accept this as the correct anwser

Comment: It is probably simpler to use the `afterDelete` function in cloud code - transactions performed in this method do not count as additional transactions for your Parse transaction limit.  If you use a background job you need to handle the potential for a "favourite" item to be no longer found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Parse class for your feed objects. After that create an array column to store objectIds of users who added your feed item to favorit. When you want to find all the objects specific user bookmarked do something like

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"feedObjects"];
[query whereKey:@"favoritesArray" equalTo:@"YOUR USER OBJECT ID"];
[query findObjectsInBackground];
```

To remove object simply do

```
PFObject *feedItem = [PFQuery getObjectOfClass:@"feedObjects" objectId:@"ITEM TO REMOVE OBJECTID"];
[feedItem deleteInBackground];
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: While this will work, it is not the best way to reduce traffic as post the query and then potentially multiple deletes over the network. A cloud code `afterDelete` function is a better approach

Comment: This is kind the opposite of the way I proposed, but actually also works. Storing the ID of the user's who bookmarked in an array on each object,  and not the object's ID in an array on each user. As I explained, my question is not how to do this, but what would be the least expensive way and, as @Paulw11 said, using Cloud Code is actually the best way to approach this. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Cloud Code yet, but I will give a try when I got more time

Comment: The query will do only one deletion as feedObjects contain only one object with needed id.

Comment: You can use any approach, my is for a lazy people who don't want to use cloud code)

Comment: @IvanNesterenko, what I'm trying to say is that despite our logic make sense, perhaps it is terrible from a practical point of view. Let's imagine that we have a very small social network, with a feed of 100 objects and 200 users. Let's say that in the worst case scenario, all users bookmarked all objects. When mounting favorites screen, the Parse would have to perform a search on 100 arrays, each one with 200 objects. This means that the service would have to look inside 20,000 items for the user ID, since each of the 100 arrays contains 200 IDs!

Comment: @IvanNesterenko I hope you understand that I am not criticizing your answer. In fact, my answer was exactly like yours, as I explained above, but what I mean is that our logic, although functional, is not the best in terms of performance. I think we really need to learn this damn Cloud Code! lol

Comment: @LeonardoPaiva yeah, after the discussion I guess that it's the only way to make things work properly is using the cloud code :)